# Can the EventBrite API be used to post events that use a registration link (i.e. 3rd party registration)?

Tags: eventbrite

I'm trying to post some free events to EventBrite via API v3. These events are free and require registration on the event source website. I would like to use a registration link (back to the source webpage) as the registration method. Can this be done via API? Can it be done at all? If so, how would I do this in the API?

Right now, I am stuck on creating tickets. I need to switch from tickets to registration, I assume.

Comment: @mitch ( http://stackoverflow.com/users/988720/mitch ) any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot link to an outside registration page if using Eventbrite. All registrations must go through the Eventbrite platform. You can find more information here https://www.eventbrite.com/tos/

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!